# how to check property value in class that resides in ArrayList from Jsp page using <c:if>

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl

i have `Arraylist` in `Request scope` , that contains all `Students` objects..
i'm displaying that data in `JSP page`

```
class Student 
  {

   int sno;
   String name;
   String type; // here type can be either R or D
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

while i'm displaying `Student obj` data  i want to check `student type`
  `if type=D` then i want add `<select>` box 
how to do this ???

i'm using `struts 1.3` and `JDBC`

my code is

```
 <logic:iterate id="student" name="allstudents" scope="request">

   <bean:write name="student"   property="sno" format="#"/><br>
   <bean:write name="student"   property="name" /><br>
   <bean:write name="student"   property="type" /><br>


   // here i want to display <select> if type =D
    .
    .
    .
 </logic:iterate>
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor, and learn the JSTL. Once done, use the `<c:forEach>`, `<c:out>`, `<fmt:formatNumber>` and  `<c:if>` tags:

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${allstudents}">

    <fmt:formatNumber value="${student.sno}" pattern="#"/>
    <c:out value="${student.name}"/>
    <c:out value="${student.type}"/>
    <c:if test="${student.type == 'D'}>
        ...
    </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i tried like this this is working fine...
thank you JB Nizet....

 <logic:iterate id="student" name="allstudents" scope="request">

       <bean:write name="student"   property="sno" format="#"/><br>
       <bean:write name="student"   property="name" /><br>
       <bean:write name="student"   property="type" /><br>


       <c:if test="${student.type == 'D'}>
       ......
       </c:if>

     </logic:iterate>
```